# Condition program flow on whether a `double?` is null

Tags: c#

In C#, you can append a question mark to a type to indicate that it may hold either a value of a type or return null:

```cs
double? MySqrt(double a)
{
    return (a > 0.0) ? Math.Sqrt(a) : null;
}

Console.WriteLine(MySqrt(4.5));     // 2.1213203435596424
Console.WriteLine(MySqrt(-4.5));    // a blank line
```

Now, if I want to condition a variable assignment the result of this function, I can use the `??` operator, e.g.

```cs
double b = MySqrt(-2.0) ?? 0.0;
Console.WriteLine(b);     // 0
```

But without redefining `MySqrt`, **how can I control the larger programmatic flow** (not just a single variable assignment) based on whether or not `MySqrt` returned `null`?

The following, for example, yields a compiler error:

```cs
void DrawSquareWithArea(double area)
{
    double sideLength = MySqrt(area);
    if (sideLength != null)
    {
        // Draw a square on the screen
        DrawSquare(sideLength);
    }
    else
    {
        // Display some visual feedback indicating that input was invalid
        DisplayErrorFeedback();
    }
}
// error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Note that the function `DrawSquare()` requires a `double` argument here, so changing `sideLength` to a `double?` is another compiler error.

Comment: The error is very clear - change `double sideLength` to either `var sideLength` or to `double? sideLength`.

Comment: That is also a compiler error, because the function DrawSquare requires a double.

Comment: `DrawSquare(sideLength.Value);` perhaps?

Comment: If you treat `double?` as a box with either `double` or nothing inside - you can extract `double` from that box by using `sideLength.Value` (but if there were nothing - it will throw an exception, though in this case you verified there is something there first).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the correct type (`Nullable<double>` a.k.a. `double?`). The non-null value can be accessed by means of the `Value` property (which has type `double` here):

```
void DrawSquareWithArea(double area)
{
    double? sideLength = MySqrt(area);
    if (sideLength != null) // or: if (sideLength.HasValue)
    {
        // Draw a square on the screen
        DrawSquare(sideLength.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        // Display some visual feedback indicating that input was invalid
        DisplayErrorFeedback();
    }
}
```

Or have the compiler infer the type:

```
var sideLength = MySqrt(area);
```

Comment: Yes, the question was edited to clarify the comment. `Value` returns the raw value (i.e. `double`)

Comment: @Max I went ahead and deleted my comment because of the edits, and your follow on comments. I feel like it's not adding any value to the answer anymore. I'll come back later to delete this comment. Feel free to delete any comments you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert explicitly `double?` to `double`. Either check for `null` and use `.Value`:

```
void DrawSquareWithArea(double area)
{
    double? sideLength = MySqrt(area);
    if (sideLength is not null)
    {
        // Draw a square on the screen
        DrawSquare(sideLength.Value); // sideLength.Value is double
    }
    //...
}
```

or use pattern matching with declaration pattern:

```
void DrawSquareWithArea(double area)
{
    if (MySqrt(area) is {} len) // checks for null and assigns variable of double type
    {
        // Draw a square on the screen
        DrawSquare(len);
    }
    //...
}
```

or :

```
void DrawSquareWithArea(double area)
{
    if (MySqrt(area) is double len) // checks for null and assigns variable of double type
    {
        // Draw a square on the screen
        DrawSquare(len);
    }
    //...
}
```

Read more:

- [Nullable value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)
- [Pattern matching overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are perfectly fine. However I would like to add another approach which could be quite handy and (from my perspective) might be even better than using null as return type.
If your method is called with a non valid value why not simply throw an exception? In your calling method, handle the thrown exception. A minimal working example could look like the following.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try{
            MySqrt(-5);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    static double MySqrt(double a)
    {
        if(a > 0.0) return Math.Sqrt(a);
        throw new ArithmeticException("Can not calculate square root of negative value!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about C#, but in the other languages I use, try/except blogs are normally used for debugging during development and aren't customarily included in production code. Is the convention different here?

Comment: Nearly all more or less complex applications can run into an exception that you can not think about during development (like in your case). So it's always good to catch exceptions at some point (at the highest level possible) in your code and handle them properly. The advantage is you can see exactly where an issue happened (if you pass the exception object up and log it). But that's just preference. I just wanted to add a different approach :)